# Compare 2 objects which are deep nested dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, equality

I have a deep nested dictionaries:

```
var a1 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>>();
var a2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>>();
```

where `Person` is some data structure containing members like `name`, `family`, `age` ...

```
public class Person
{
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string family{ get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

I want to compare between
a1 and a2 and especially between the `Person's` members.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Define "best". One of the most convenient ways is serializing to JSON and then comparing, even though this is shockingly inefficient. In general, moving away from nested dictionaries and towards things like records (which offer value comparison semantics for free) might also be a good idea.

Comment: actually I do that inside a unit test

Comment: Many testing frameworks do have convenience methods for structural comparisons (like Fluent Assertions' `Should().BeEquivalentTo()`). Where these methods do not support dictionaries a simple LINQ query to convert things to list-based (ordered) key-value pairs would do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution that I can think of as deep comparison of objects is not given by libraries just because it is not a trivial task to define in a generic way that would cover most use cases. For you specific one it is fairly easy to implement. You just need to write 2 methods on that compares dictionaries and one that compares the objects:

```
void Compare<T, G>(Dictionary<T, G> first, Dictionary<T, G> second)
{
    foreach (var item in first)
    {
        if (!second.ContainsKey(item.Key)) Assert.Fail();

        var secondValue = second[item.Key];

        Compare(item.Value, secondValue);
    }
}

void Compare<T>(T first, T second)
{
    if (first is Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>> f)
    {
        Compare(f, (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>>)(object)second);
    }
    else if (first is Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>> f1)
    {
        Compare(f1, (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Person>>)(object)second);
    }
    else if (first is Dictionary<string, Person> f2)
    {
        Compare(f2, (Dictionary<string, Person>)(object)second);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(property.GetValue(first), property.GetValue(second));
        }
    }
}
```

there is a lot not covered by this code snippet but you can expand of it to match your use cases.

Comment: Is there an linq option to flattening the nested dictionary into string?

Comment: you can flatten it just by `first.SelectMany(x=> x.Value.SelectMany(z=> z.Value.SelectMany(y=> ($"{x.key}.{z.key}.{y.key}",y.value)))` and assuming the dot concatenation is good enough to not introduce conflicts you can compare flattened version as if it was single dictionary; I do not think it is worth it